# Is it possible to dynamically change from FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN to FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS?

Tags: c++, windows, linux

Good afternoon, We are building a prototype of a Windows/LINUX deduper using the memory mapped file API of Windows and Linux. Our deduper starts out by doing a sequential scan of all the database records to be deduped. Therefore , we pass the flag FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN to the Windows API CreateFile during our intial sequential scan of the database records to be deduped.
   Once we finish the first part of our deduping process, we try to use the Windows memory mapping API to randomly access the data. At this point, using the Windows C++ API, is it possible to dynamically change to the FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS mode?

```
In Linux, we are are able to do this with the following excerpt of code, 
  MapPtr = (char*)mmap((void *)BaseMapPtr ,mappedlength,PROT_READ, 
            MAP_PRIVATE,  hFile,baseoff );
                    if (MapPtr == MAP_FAILED){
                        perror("mmap");
                        throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,TempFileName);
                    }
 madvise(MapPtr,mappedlength,MADV_RANDOM);
```

Are we paying a penalty in Windows by using FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN  during the random access phase of our deduping process. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The caching hint flags passed to CreateFile() do not affect the manner in which the memory manager satisfies page faults generated by de-referencing an address within a mapped section.  Such I/Os use the same  - they use the same cache pages as regular I/O.

That said, when a handle to the file is created with FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, the cache manager *may* perform read-ahead operations (and may even read the entire file into memory, if system conditions allow for this).  Which means that that you may encounter fewer hard page faults if you sequentially access the pages of the mapped file.

it seems to me that you'd be best served by simply re-using the handle you've created during your de-dup processing.  Closing and re-opening may cause previously cached pages of the file to be discarded, depending on cache pressure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just accepted your answer. I will change our code to reuse the handle we have created during our dedup processing. We noticed that when a file handle is created with FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, that we encounter fewer hard page faults when we sequentially access the pages of the mapped file. Does that mean we do not try to use the FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS during our dedup processing? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank - Your mileage may vary.  When FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS is specified, read-ahead will be disabled for the handle.  Additionally, the cache manager will be less aggressive in unmapping previously visited pages of the file - the idea here is to minimized the mapping/unmapping events for the file when the application revisits pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think we will try to run our deduping application with CreateFile(...,FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS) in order to minimize the  mapping/unmapping events for the memory mapped file when the deduping application revisits pages. It should be interesting to the see the results. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A description of how FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN works can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/98756

As it is only used with the CreateFile function, there's no way to update it once the file is opened. You may always close the file and reopen it with a different flag.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I just accepted your answer. Are you suggesting that after the first sequential scanning phase of our deduper, we close the file. Then , during the final random access phase, should we reopen the file with the FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS? Will this affect  our ability to use the Window Memory Mapping File API? Thank you.

Comment: We are trying your suggestion right now. So we: 1. close(hFile) 2. hFile = CreateFile((LPTSTR) TempFileName,.... Flags_ | FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS); 3. Distance_.LowPart = (ULONG)FileSize_; Distance_.HighPart = 0; 4. dwPtr = ::SetFilePointer(hFile,Distance_.LowPart, &(Distance_.HighPart), FileBegin); 5. SetEndOfFile(hFile); 6. hMapping=::CreateFileMapping(hFile,(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *)Security_,PAGE_READWRITE,0,0,0); Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: The flag you pass does not affect the proper operation of file I/O, it only affects the efficiency because of buffering. It's entirely possible that memory mapping bypasses the buffering completely, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I guess the only way we determine if the memory mapping bypasses  the buffering completely, is to profile the code after yor suggestion? We will try to let you know the results of our test tonight. Thank you.

Comment: I apolgize for not letting you know the results of our last night. I had to rebuild my sqlite database. I was wondering you read @Buke's answer(above). Are you and @Bukes saying basically the same idea? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to back up @Burkes answer: as you mentioned that you were "using the memory mapped file API of Windows" it should be noted that [Raymond Chen warns the cache hints have no affect on effect on memory mapped I/O](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120120-00/?p=8493):

> Note: These cache hints apply only if you use Read­File (or moral equivalents). Memory-mapped file access does not go through the cache manager, and consequently these cache hints have no effect.

So what happens to already be cached may help but future memory mapped accesses will not help the cache be populated/depopulated.